# How can I format the results of a code block in Org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

Consider for the sake of an example the following code block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC scheme :exports both
  (atan 0.0 -1.0)
#+END_SRC
```

When I export this file, Org inserts the result (which is the number Pi) into the output.  So far, so good.  I would like to format this result (e.g. typeset it in italics).  How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think org is going to let you do that internally, a code block is semantically unitalicized, unbolded, fixed-width text. To accomplish this you'd probably need to modify the hardcoded style. CSS if html, or some kind of macro if exporting to LaTeX.